# Multiple submit button with ajax submit on asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need multiple submit button usage with ajax submit on asp.net core mvc.

I should be able to distinguish.

Anyone help me about it ? Thanks.

my .cshtml file:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="DuyuruEdit" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
......
....
...
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
            <input type="submit" name="release" value="Release" />
</form>

<script>
       $("#myform").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("DuyuruEdit", "Duyuru")',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    getLoadPanelInstance().show();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'İşlem Başarılı!',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 1000
                    }).then(function () {
                        location.reload();
                    });
                },
                error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Bir Hata Oldu...',
                        text: textStatus.responseText
                    });
                },
                complete: function () {
                    getLoadPanelInstance().hide();
                }
            });

                return true;
        });
```

and my c# file. it is not doing anything. Parameters come null.

I should be able to distinguish

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult DuyuruEdit(DuyuruEditViewModel mdl,string save,string release)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(save))
            {

            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(release))
            {

            }
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need multiple submit button usage with ajax submit on asp.net core
> mvc.

If you want to implement on the basis of `ajax`, I think [@Imran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63148385/12884742) provides a correct idea, but based on your js method, his solution can not completely solve your problem, you need to **get the name of the submit button** instead of getting the form id.

Here is a complete case, please refer to it:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="DuyuruEdit" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="Name" type="text" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="Data" type="text" /><br />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" name="release" value="Release" />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        var clickButtonName;
        $("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
            clickButtonName = $(this).attr("name");
        });
       $("#myform").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
           var formData = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("DuyuruEdit", "Duyuru")?saveOrRelease=' + clickButtonName ,
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                //other code
            });
                return true;
       });
    </script>
}
```

My DuyuruEditViewModel:

```
 public class DuyuruEditViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult DuyuruEdit(DuyuruEditViewModel mdl, string saveOrRelease)
        {
            if(saveOrRelease == "save")
            {
                
            }
            if (saveOrRelease == "release")
            {

            }
            return View();
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Good to provide complete solution. But Submit button could be get in Submit function as I mentioned. No need to use separate function like `$("input[type=submit]")`

Comment: @Imran, In fact, I used your code to test. In the submit function, `e.target.id` gets the id of the form, not the id of the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

Give Id's to both submit buttons e.g. `id="btnSave"` and `id="btnRelease"` Inside submit function, Check the button click through the id's as:

```
var btnClicked = e.target.id;
```

Then pass the value of this `btnClicked` to controller action through `@Url.Action`.

```
url: '@Url.Action("DuyuruEdit", "Duyuru", new { btnSubmit = btnClicked })',
```

In controller action, no need to use separate parameters for both buttons. Only one parameter would be `string=btnSubmit`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Release" />

public IActionResult DuyuruEdit(DuyuruEditViewModel mdl,string action) {
    if(action=="Save") 
         dostuff

    if(action=="Release") 
        dostuff
}
```